# AngularJS Textarea If data Is loading

Tags: angularjs

I have a textarea that relies upon a dropdown menu to populate. When the dropdown is changed, a file is pulled and the contents are loaded to the textarea.

While the textarea is loading, it just says `[object Object]`. I'd like it to be a bit nicer than that. Something like 'Loading...'.

I cant find  away to specifically do this with a textarea though.

Another wrench in the wheel is that the Save functionality actually relies upon the value of the text area to save, so I cant just alter the content of the text area to display 'Saving...' otherwise the content that is written to the file is just 'Saving...'.

Here is the code:

**View**

```
<div id="Options" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon input-sm">Config Select</span>
                <select ng-change="update()" ng-model="configFileName" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option>--</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="conf in configList" value="{{conf.name}}">{{conf.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <td style="padding-bottom: .5em;" class="text-muted">Config File</td><br />
                <textarea id="textareaEdit" rows="20" cols="46" ng-model="configFileContent"></textarea>
                <input type="button" ng-click="updateConfig()" style="width: 90px;" value="Save"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.update = (function(param) {
    $scope.configFileContent = 'Loading...';
    $scope.configFileContent = $api.request({
        module: 'Radius',
        action: 'getConfigFileContent',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $scope.configFileName
    }, function(response) {
        $timeout(function() {
            console.log('got it');
            $scope.configFileContent = response.confFileContent;
        }, 2000);
    });
});

$scope.updateConfig = (function(param) {
    var data = [$scope.configFileName, $scope.configFileContent];
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    $scope.configFileContent = $api.request({
        module: 'Radius',
        action: 'saveConfigFileContent',
        method: 'POST',
        data: json
    }, function(response) {
        $timeout(function() {
            console.log('Saved!');
            $scope.update();

        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.update = function() {
        if ($scope.selectedData === '') {
            $scope.someData = '';
            return;
        }
        // do http response
        var data = 'dummy file text from server';

        $scope.xhr = false;

        $scope.msg = 'loading...';

        // simulating fetch request
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.xhr = true;
            $scope.content = data;
        }, 3000);
      }
    });

  </script>

  <div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select ng-model="selectedData" ng-change="update()">
      <option selected="selected" value="">Select data</option>
      <option value="foo">Fetch my data</option>
    </select>
      <br><br><br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" ng-model="someData" ng-value="xhr === false ? msg : content">
    </textarea>
  </div>
```

You can use a scope variable to detect the completion of promise request of xhr and simulate a loading... message.

As for save, i recommend not to use such approach of displaying message inside textarea and instead create another directive/component to detect the loading and saving request completion which is reusable and separates business logic keeping controller thin.